# How to included CTAs and Quick Reply in direct messaging V2 API (Not v1.1)

Tags: twitter-api-v2

In Twitter Direct Messages API V2, there is an option to send messages and attachments, however, there is no option to send the buttons (CTAs and Quick Reply).

How do we include buttons (CTAs and Quick Reply) in Direct Message V2 API?

If there is no such option, is there any alternatives?

API Ref: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/direct-messages/manage/api-reference/post-dm_conversations-with-participant_id-messages

Note: API v1.1 is not supported with the Basic plan.